# Iteration of a variable over a set of strings

Tags: string, list, for-loop

I am fairly new to Python and I would like to know if I could define a for loop that iterates over a list of strings. For instance,

```
for Color in ['Black','Yellow','Green']:
    if Color == 'Black':
       # Do something
...
```

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, and that's just about the way you'd do it. (though if you already know `'Black'`, I don't know why you're looking for it...

As a side note, python style says variable names get snake_case (lowercase, with underscores as word separators) so `Color` should be `color`
Also, use spaces after your commas.